# In Drupal, show node titles in list but limit access to individual node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Using Drupal 7, I'm trying to create a view that display a list of a certain type of nodes for all users, including anonymous, but the individual nodes in that list are only available for certain roles (particularly excluding anonymous).  In other words, an anonymous user would be able to see all of the available nodes in the list, but clicking on a title to view the full node would results in being redirected to a different, specific "Sign up to see more" basic page node.

My question is mostly about the permissions; I'm pretty sure I can use the rules module for the redirection, though ideas on that would also be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need Rules.
You can create a View with this node titles, and set up permissions using Content permissions module: https://drupal.org/project/content_access

And for redirects, you have 2 options:

- Set the default 403 page in Site information to user/login
- Use this module: https://drupal.org/project/r4032login

Regards.